# Cannot create queue connection factory in Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I am using Apache Camel in my project and embedding that in Spring Boot application. My requirement is to read message from an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis (Embedded in JBoss EAP 7.2.0) write message to an IBM MQ. Both the queues are remote to my current server. The Spring Boot project will be deployed as a war file to JBoss EAP 7.2.0 server.

I have developed a standalone program that would read message from and write message to an Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. I have created the connection factory in Spring Boot configuration class. Below is my Spring Boot configuration class and route class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class SpringMqDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMqDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Retrieving JMS queue with JNDI name: " + CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
            jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(CONNECTION_FACTORY);

            jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
            jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

            return (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while retrieving JMS queue with JNDI name: [" + CONNECTION_FACTORY + "]");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Properties getEnvProperties() {
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://<<IP>>:8080");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        return env;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();

        jndiDestinationResolver.setJndiEnvironment(getEnvProperties());
        factory.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver);
        return factory;
    }

    @Component
    public class Route extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:producer")
                .log("Camel route")
                .to("jms:queue:queue1");
            
            from("jms:queue:queue2")
                .log("Camel route: ${body}")
                .to("someEndpoint");
        }       
    }
```

With this sample program, I was able to write to queue1 and read from queue2, but here I am using the same ConnectionFactory for both the queues. In my project, I will have to use two connection factories, can anyone please guide me how to use two connection factories for both the queues?

I went through the documentation of JMS endpoint but am not sure what value should I use for the parameter "connectionFactory" on camel JMS endpoint.

Comment: Did you read [Camel's documentation on the JMS component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html)? If so, what was lacking? Please be specific.

Comment: I had read the documentation and it does not say about where to create a connection factory. It says how we can use a connection factory. I want to know where the connection factory will be created in order to use it on camel endpoint.

Comment: Did you read the bit about [using JNDI to find the connection factory](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_using_jndi_to_find_the_connectionfactory)? Please clarify why that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I have explained my problem in detail, hope this will help in understanding my exact problem.